# How to print my easy jet e-ticket with evince?

Tags: linux, pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat, evince

When i try to display a pdf file containg a easy jet flight ticket using linux debian evince 3.12.1 rending displays overlapped characters various places of ticket and on console i got many message lines like this :

Syntax Warning: font matrix not invertible<0a>

I tried to do it through the browser but this is even worse, browser complains it does not support filling of forms ( this is a french message so i translated it ) and page is fully blank.

Is there a way to fix it, what other pdf viewer can i use to get it right ?

I tried to get a acrobat reader on site but there is not more linux version ( only windows, mac & android ). Since i might not be the only one to print flight tickets with linux, i guess there is an easy solution.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 i read your possible duplicate, and none of the asnwers are satisifying.

Comment: Doesn't make it a different problem/question.  You are having problems printing certain PDFs in Evince.  So far it appears to be an compatibility problem.  Either file a bug report, use an alternative reader, and/or try updating your CUPS server.  If the existing answers aren't satisfying, and you'd like newer/different answers on the existing question, please consider [placing a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on it.

Comment: You can add a bounty to the other question right now.

Comment: @KevinPanko, you are right, i didn't even think about that way ( bounty for a question already answered ). I expected to find it on google with "easyjet eticket + evince + Syntax Warning: font matrix not invertible". That's why this question is for me not the very same than a wider one. And now i answered my question with xpdf solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using xpdf version 3.03 displays it correctly.
Printing to file .ps then using evince to print from .ps did the trick.

xpdf 3.03 uses libpoppler.so.46.

Comment: Accroding to https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince , support of PDF using the Poppler backend. Perhaps for very latest version or what ?